# How to call controller method to written string when call from jsp c for each loop

Tags: spring, jsp

1. How to call controller method in jsp **C For each Loop** like 
       to get string return from **controller method??**

Answer (score 0):

The paradigm here works differently when compared e.g. to jsf. Spring controller is responsible for "precomputing" your data and returning them in a model when constructing the view. In order to get a new value from controller you should either reconstruct a page or use AJAX. However, in order to be able to use your value in a c for each, you need to include it in the view's model.